# How to find missing record from a file?

Tags: sql, file

Edited:

There is a file has 5000 records that are parsed and loaded into Oracle database table. after the completing the process the results will be logged into a file that will show the success and failure counts. There it has only 4999 records are success. 1 record is not inserted (may be it not formatted correctly).

I need to find out the record from file that was not loaded into database. it not easy to check the record one by one. Is there any simple way to do it?

thanks

Comment: I think you will need to provide more detail. *What* is loading these records? SQL*Loader?

Comment: am sorry, that was mistake in my question. Please take a look at it now, updated!

Comment: could it be that you make your loop from an entry number 1 instead of 0 and you miss the first entry? or that the first line is a title line and you only have 4999 entries? this kind of mistakes happen a lot.

Comment: Nope there is no wrong with the system. It is the problem with file format only. I am sure...

Answer (score 0):

I must agree with @Adam Paynter in that you give very little detail about how and what is inserting the data.

Said this, if you can delete and reinsert those 4000 records I would suggest to change your loading procedure so that when an insertion fails it puts into the log the values that SQLCODE and SQLERRM return plus the record data.

You should then easily see what caused the error and which record is failing.

EDIT: since you can not touch the import source nor the data in the table you could try to
create your own "import" procedure to check against the table data. It should be something in the style of:

1. For each record in the file get all the necessary fields to univoquely identify a record.
2. Check against the table if a record with that exact data exists. If the answer is yes go to step 1.
3. If the answer is no, you got the missing record.

HTH